# AngularJS. Формат ответа $http запроса

Tags: angularjs, http, promise

Делаю запрос на сервер:

```
 angular
        .module('mainApp')
        .controller('profileCtrl',profileCtrl);

    function profileCtrl($http,$scope) {
        $scope.getProfileData=function (userId) {
            var promise = $http({
                url: basePath+'/studentReg/getProfileData',
                method: "POST",
                data: $.param({id: userId}),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'}
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log('inside');
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;
            }, function errorCallback() {
                return false;
            });
            return promise;
        };
        console.log('outside');
        console.log($scope.getProfileData(userId));
    }
```

В консоли выводится:

```
   outside
    d {$$state: Object}$$state: Object status: 1 
->value: id: "56" firstName: "Во'вав" fidentity: "" state: "0"...
```

и

```
inside
Object {id: "56", firstName: "Во'вав", identity: "", state: "0"...}
```

Почему такая разница в формате вывода между `response.data` и `promise` ? Как правильно присвоить переменной результат запроса, чтобы можно было обращаться к элементам обьекта как-то так:`$scope.getProfileData.id` и т.д. В том варианте в котором выводит в примере, достучатся к `value` не смог

П.С.Сервер возвращает `echo json_encode($model->attributes);`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему такая разница в формате вывода между *response.data* и *promise*?

Потому что объекты разных типов, `response.data` - обработанный результат запроса, а promise - объект который может быть в нескольких состояниях и никак не связан с запросом. Вполне логично что и вывод у них разный.

> Как правильно присвоить переменной результат запроса, чтобы можно было обращаться к элементам объекта как-то так:`$scope.getProfileData.id` и т.д

Никак, так как операция асинхронная. Только в обработчике `then` для успешного, либо ошибочного состояния promise.

В зависимости от задачи решения могут быть различными: начиная от того, что вам не нужно в контроллере пользоваться значением вне `then`, и заканчивая использованием `ngResource` которое прокидывается сразу во view, либо ожиданием пока promise перейдет в статус resolve, на этапе изменения state, либо route

Answer (score 1):

Можно без присваивания результата запроса переменной сразу его возвращать:

```
$scope.getProfileData=function (userId) {
    return $http({
        url: basePath+'/studentReg/getProfileData',
        method: "POST",
        data: $.param({id: userId}),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('inside');
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
    }, function errorCallback() {
        return false;
    });
};
```